# Servidor wildfly

Tags: java, servidor, wildfly

**Standalone do wildfly**

```
<interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
           <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <any-address/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>

    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8100}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

Acesso somente localhost. Não consigo acessar em outro local. Precisa configurar mais algo ?

A porta **8100** e **9990**, está liberada no firewall do windows server 2008.

Comment: Não consegue acessar a `8100` ou a `9990`? Se for a `9990` deve alterar a configuração da interface `management`.

Comment: Nenhuma das duas portas

Answer (score 2):

Geralmente você precisa mexer no `wildfly.conf` e editar a variável de ambiente JBOSS_OPTS para que ele "escute" outras interfaces; para que ele responda em todas é algo assim:

```
JBOSS_OPTS="-b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement=0.0.0.0"
```

Estes parâmetros são utilizados quando o servidor é iniciado.

Comment: No arquivo **wildfly.conf**, ficou assim: **JBOSS_OPTS="-b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement=0.0.0.0"**, mas não funcionou.

Antes de alterar, parei o servidor. Fiz as alterações. Reiniciei o servidor.